# How to improve upon this?

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are n groups of friends staying in the queue in front of bus station. The i-th group consists of ai men. Also, there is a single bus that works on the route. The size of the bus is x, that is it can transport x men simultaneously.

When the bus comes (it always comes empty) to the bus station, several groups from the head of the queue goes into the bus. Of course, groups of friends don't want to split, so they go to the bus only if the bus can hold the whole group. In the other hand, none wants to lose his position, that is the order of groups never changes.

The question is: how to choose the size x of the bus in such a way that the bus can transport all the groups and everytime when the bus moves off the bus station there is no empty space in the bus (the total number of men inside equals to x)?

Input Format:

The first line contains the only integer n (1≤n≤10^5). The second line contains n space-separated integers a1,a2,…,an (1≤ai≤10^4).

Output Format:

Print all the possible sizes of the bus in the increasing order.

Sample:

```
8
1 2 1 1 1 2 1 3
```

Output:
    3 4 6 12

I made this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int max=0,sum=0,i,n;
    cin>>n;
    int values[100000];

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
         cin>>values[i];
         sum = sum + values[i];
        if ( values[i] > max )
            max = values[i];
    }
    int p = 0,j;
    int count = 0;
    vector<int> final;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        p = p + values[i];
        j = 0;
        if ( p >= max && sum%p == 0)
        {
            flag = 0;
            while ( j < n )
            {
                garb = p;
                while (garb!= 0)
                {
                    garb = garb - values[j++];
                    if ( garb < 0 )
                        flag = 1;
                }

            }
            if ( flag == 0 )
            {
                final.push_back(p);
                count++;
            }
        }
     }
        sort(final.begin(),final.end());
        for ( j = 0; j < count; j++ )
        {
            cout<<final[j]<<"\t";   
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Edit: I did this in which basically, I am checking if the found divisor satisfies the condition, and if at any point of time, I get a negative integer on taking difference with the values, I mark it by using a flag. However, it seems to give me a seg fault now. Why?

I firstly, calculated the maximum value out of the all possible values, and then, I checked if its a divisor of the sum of the values. However, this approach doesn't work for the input as:

```
10
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2
```

My output is
    `2 7 14`
whereas the output should be
    `7 14` 
only.
Any other approach that I can go with?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: [bus station in hacker rank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116965/bus-station-in-hacker-rank)

Comment: look closely at what happens in the first iteration of your second for loop. especially the "p>=max".

Comment: Original contest problem on Hacker Rank: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101jul14/challenges/bus-station

Comment: @John Doe, I know what is the problem with my code. I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @PaulR, I actually tried solving it. I passed almost all the test cases barring a few. I don't know how can I solve them.

Comment: @PaulIR If you know whats wrong with your code then fix it before asking questions. I cannot and I will not predict what you already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @PaulIR Try to validate your solution before printing it out. So you would notice that the 2 is wrong. e.g. in a loop over all your solutions.

Comment: @JohnDoe, check it now. I have updated the code.

Comment: @JohnDoe: I think you're addressing your comments to the wrong person ? The OP is user3776323.

Comment: @PaulR You are right. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can any of you address the problem now.

Comment: @user3776323 So did the output change? Is garb a signed or unsigned variable?

Comment: didnt see you get seg fault. Try to debug it and find out where and when it happens.

Comment: @JohnDoe, `garb` is a signed value. And also, If I would have been able to find out where it happens, I wouldnt have posted it here. Also, seg fault is coming only for this specific input which I have posted.

Comment: So if you have debugged it. In which line and at which iteration do you get seg fault?

Comment: I dont know that. I put this in as the input, and I get seg fault.

Comment: Well then it's time to learn how to use a debugger. Or put in some cout in your code which tell you in which loop you are and the value of the current loop counter. And then read the last message you get before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following simple solution (since your present concern is correctness and not time complexity):

1. Calculate the sum of all ai's (as you are already doing).
2. Calculate the maximum of all ai's (as you are already doing).
3. Find all the factors of sum that are > max(ai).
4. For each factor, iterate through the ai's and check whether the bus condition is satisfied.